# Selecting specific part of an HTML text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function that returns some HTML fragment **that I store in a variable called *data***, with its whole structure. What I want is to extract from it some of those parts.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script id="hello">

    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

For example, I want to get the body and save it in a new variable:

```
var body = data.split("<body")[1].split(">").slice(1).join(">").split("</body>")[0];
```

Where *data* is the HTML text as a **string** that the original function is returning.

Is there any way I could save an specific script, from its ID (in this case with id = hello), and save it in another variable??

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

```
var newVar = $("#hello").html();
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose you have an HTML string in a variable, for example

```
var foo = '<body><span>bar</span></body>';
```

Now, let's initialize a parser, to convert this into HTML:

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(foo, "text/html");
```

Now, you can read anything from `foo`, as it is converted into HTML:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML = doc.querySelectorAll("body")[0].innerHTML;
```

Comment: Ok... It looks like it gets closer to what I need... but i dont understand the last line, when you do `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML = doc.querySelectorAll("body")[0].innerHTML;`

Comment: @MartaLobo it replaces the inner html of the body of your document with the inner html of the body of your variable template. This was just an example about writing stuff from a variable into your document. You can virtually do anything.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$html = document.querySelector("body").innerHTML;
$hello = document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML;
console.log($html);
console.log($hello);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script id="hello">
        // script data
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: querySelector it says it is not a function

Comment: @MartaLobo did you see it failing in the snippet? For sure there might be a difference to get an error.

Comment: In my code the HTML is saved as a string, so I cant access it using html functions, thats why I use split and slice and join with the body

Comment: @MartaLobo if it is in an `HTML` string then use `DOMParser` before

Comment: could you show me how? I can't still make it work Y.Y

Comment: @MartaLobo just implement the example of the answer using of `Lajos Arpad` using `DOMParser` in case of errors check your string for errors.